# Softkeyboard when open add space at the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-statusbar

I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"` in the manifest. In my styles.xml I have:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

The root layout of this fragment has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. But the problem comes when I open the keyboard there's a gray space at the top(status bar), I have no clue why it does that, even if I dismiss the keyboard it's still there. It's not there only when I first open the fragment.

[image: When fragment first open]

[image: When keyboard is open]

Comment: it depends on the values you have set on the text view. That area is the space where spelling corrections or suggestions would normally appear

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the post. The gray space I'm referring to is the new status bar. Like the current translucent status bar has been replace, and it's no longer full screen.